# PHP need to uppercase text inside double square bracket

Tags: php

I need help to uppercase the text inside double square bracket. for example :

I want to turn below :

```
hi, [[i]] want [[this]] to be [[uppercase]]
```

Resulting as below:

```
hi, [[I]] want [[THIS]] to be [[UPPERCASE]]
```

When I use below code everything turns everything into uppercase:

```
$pattern = '/\[\[(.*)\]\]/';
$new_string = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 
    function($match)
    {
        return strtoupper($match[0]);
    }
    , $string);
```

what is missing in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is greedy it wants everything..

Change

```
$pattern = '/\[\[(.*)\]\]/';
```

to

```
$pattern = '/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/';
```

Here are some links on the topic if you need more informtation.

[What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)
http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html